# Определить город пользователя

Tags: yandex-maps-api

У меня по геолокации Яндекс определяет как Череповец
https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/geolocation

При этом, Яндекс (в приватном режиме) определяют город правильно - Москва.

Какие есть способы через Яндекс определить города пользователя на сайте?

Comment: может у вас расширение включено и весь трафик через прокси идёт, а в приватном режиме расширение выключено и вас определяют нормально

Comment: Прокси нет, меня почти все сайты определяют как Череповец.

При этом geolocation в приватном режиме определяет как Череповец, но перехожу на сайт Яндекс, меня определят как Москва.

Comment: Проверьте, что показывает Интернетометр - https://yandex.ru/internet/ в обычном и инкогнито режимах. И если там также Череповец, пишите в поддержку.

Comment: Спасибо!
Как такое может быть:
Регион по IP-адресу: Череповец
Регион: Москва

Comment: Таблицы геопривязок IP-адресов могут быть устаревшими. Скопируйте данные интернетометра и отправьте в поддержку - проверят и скорректируют, если подтвердится.

Comment: Каким образом Яндекс знает, что регион Москва, при этом указывает, Регион по IP-адресу: Череповец. Можно ли как-то через Яндекс API получить информацию по региону?